# Using booktabs with newcommand

Tags: tables, macros, booktabs

I'm relatively new to defining commands and environments. I'm trying to make several tables (all of which follow a template), and thought that defining myself a new command would simplify the code. Here's what I tried:

```
\newcommand{test}[6]{
    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        \centering
        \toprule

        \textbf{Form} & \textbf{Conjugation} \\
        \midrule

        \textit{Yo} & \textit{#1} \\
        \textit{T\'u} & \textit{#2} \\
        \textit{\'El} & \textit{#3} \\
        \textit{Nosot@s} & \textit{#4} \\
        \textit{Vosotr@s} & \textit{#5} \\
        \textit{Ell@s} & \textit{#6} \\

        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
}
```

Basically, I'd like to be able to enter 6 parameters, and have it fill in those parameters and print the corresponding table.

Unfortunately, this code doesn't work. Do you know how to get it to work?

Thank you!

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Move `\centering` from inside `tabular` to before tabular. If you like to have centered cells' contents, than replace `l` columns type with `c`.

Comment: Trust me: you want neither `table` nor `centering` in your code.

Comment: Do not write `T\'u` or `\'El`. This is the way of type Spanish in prehistoric ages, that is no longer necessary. In a file with UTF8  (the usual today) you can type just  `Tú` and `Él` (but note that the correct for  a verb conjugation is "Tu" and "El", without accents). By the way, note also that [the RAE do not accept the inclusive language usig the @](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg#22).

Comment: @Fran I'm using LInux, and I don't think my keyboard supports accent marks (I don't think there's an easy way to support accent marks)

Comment: @egreg this is just a sample, but I'm planning to add a caption and a label. Doesn't that have to go between `tabular` and `table`? And what would be your solution to not using `\centering`?  want the table centered on the page.

Comment: @Froggos What? I am using Linux too. Of course that Linux supports accent marks: á ä â ñ Ñ ... but this is off-topic here.  Ask in https://unix.stackexchange.com if you have problems  to fix the keyboard  configuration of your system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a more flexible macro, that allows to choose between using `table` (when the key `caption` is used in the optional argument) or just producing the `tabular`.

The `placement` key (default value `htp`) can be added along with the other options.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\conjugation}{O{}m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { froggos/conjugation } { #1 }
  \froggos_conjugation:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
 }

\keys_define:nn { froggos/conjugation }
 {
  placement    .tl_set:N  = \l__froggos_conjugation_placement_tl,
  placement    .initial:n = htp,
  caption      .tl_set:N  = \l__froggos_conjugation_caption_tl,
  shortcaption .tl_set:N  = \l__froggos_conjugation_shortcaption_tl,
  label        .tl_set:N  = \l__froggos_conjugation_label_tl,
 }

\seq_new:N \l__froggos_conjugation_entries_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \froggos_conjugation:n
 {
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__froggos_conjugation_caption_tl
   {
    \__froggos_conjugation_table_begin:V \l__froggos_conjugation_placement_tl
    \centering
   }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__froggos_conjugation_entries_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Form} & \textbf{Conjugation} \\
    \midrule
    \textit{Yo}       & \textit{\seq_item:Nn \l__froggos_conjugation_entries_seq {1}} \\
    \textit{T\'u}     & \textit{\seq_item:Nn \l__froggos_conjugation_entries_seq {2}} \\
    \textit{\'El}     & \textit{\seq_item:Nn \l__froggos_conjugation_entries_seq {3}} \\
    \textit{Nosotr@s} & \textit{\seq_item:Nn \l__froggos_conjugation_entries_seq {4}} \\
    \textit{Vosotr@s} & \textit{\seq_item:Nn \l__froggos_conjugation_entries_seq {5}} \\
    \textit{Ell@s}    & \textit{\seq_item:Nn \l__froggos_conjugation_entries_seq {6}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l__froggos_conjugation_caption_tl
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l__froggos_conjugation_shortcaption_tl
     {
      \caption{\l__froggos_conjugation_caption_tl}
     }
     {
      \caption[\l__froggos_conjugation_shortcaption_tl]{\l__froggos_conjugation_caption_tl}
     }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l__froggos_conjugation_label_tl
     {
      \label{\l__froggos_conjugation_label_tl}
     }
    \end{table}
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__froggos_conjugation_table_begin:n
 {
  \begin{table}[#1]
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__froggos_conjugation_table_begin:n {V}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\section{Main}

\conjugation{soy \\ eres \\ es \\ somos \\ sois \\ son}

\conjugation[
  caption=Conjugation of \textit{ser},
  label=verb:ser,
]{soy \\ eres \\ es \\ somos \\ sois \\ son}

\conjugation[
  caption={Conjugation of \textit{ser}, but with a very long caption that requires a short one},
  shortcaption=Conjugation of \textit{ser},
  label=verb:ser-again,
]{soy \\ eres \\ es \\ somos \\ sois \\ son}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! One more question: I tried to adjust the table positioning with the `[H]` parameter, right after the `\begin{table}`. The table placement was fixed, but the letters `[htp]` are printed to the left of the table. Do you know why that is/ how to fix the issue?

Comment: @Froggos Avoid the `H` specifier. That's all. Anyway, if you insist in bad typography, use the option `placement=H`,